# Не отображается логотип в шапке

Tags: html, css, header

Логотип по сути есть, через код в браузере его контейнер просматривается (https://i.stack.imgur.com/tffst.jpg), но он не отображается, будто чем-то перекрыт. Не могу понять, в чём проблема? Вроде всё нормально в коде.

```html
(HTML) <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles\newstyle.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:400,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum&display=swap&subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body class="body">
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="F:/Site/index.html" src="F:\Site\pics\logo.png" class="logo"></a>
            <div class="nav">
                <ul class="nav_ul">
                    <li class="nav_li"><a href="#" class="nav_a">Главная</a></li>
                    <li class="nav_li"><a href="#" class="nav_a">О нас</a></li>
                    <li class="nav_li"><a href="#" class="nav_a">Контакты</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="main">
        <div>
            пример текста пример текста пример текста пример текста пример текста пример текста пример текста пример текста пример текста пример текста пример текста пример текста пример текста пример текста пример текста пример текста пример текста пример текста пример текста пример текста пример текста пример текста пример текста пример текста
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="footer_container">
            <div class="col-1-4">Текст<br>Текст<br>Текст</div>
            <div class="col-1-4">Текст<br>Текст<br>Текст</div>
            <div class="col-1-4">Текст<br>Текст<br>Текст</div>
            <div class="col-1-4">Текст<br>Текст<br>Текст</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```css
(CSS) @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:400,800&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum&display=swap&subset=cyrillic');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

.body {
    background-image: url(example.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: sandybrown;
    max-width: auto;
}

/* Шапка */

.container {

    width: auto;
    padding: 0 10% 0 5%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    display: flex;

    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 200px;
}

.header {
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.nav {
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
}
.nav_ul {
    list-style: none; 
}
.nav_li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 20%;
}

.nav_a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Центральный контент */

.main {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Подвал */

.footer {
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: gray;
}

.footer_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.col-1-4 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У браузера нет доступа к файловой системе компьютера по ряду причин.Вы же пытаетесь подключить изображение именно оттуда.

Такая конструкция `src="F:\Site\pics\logo.png"` работать не будет. Вам надо прописать относительный путь, например `/pics/logo.png`.

Более подробно читайте на [htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/faq/theme/img/add)